# How to join a vector of strings with a delimiter prepended to each string?

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for something like `join` but with the delimiter going in front of each string rather than just acting as a separator.

As a simple example, I'm looking for a less ugly version of this:

```
(def params [1 2 3 4])
(clojure.string/join (for [x params] (str "&param=" x)))
```

result

```
"&param=1&param=2&param=3&param=4"
```

Comment: I agree with @amalloy that your original version reads the easiest.

Comment: Is this query params-like syntax just to show the problem or are you actually building up query params for use in e.g. a website or passing them to some webservice?

Comment: @cfrick I'm actually building up repeating query params.

Comment: Then i'd not bang strings together (and muss the url encoding most likely) but use the facilities of the library.  E.g. in clj-http using just `{:query {:params [1 2 3 4 5]}}` just works

Answer (score 4):

Calling `(clojure.string/join coll)` with no separator is the same as `(apply str coll)` which is a tiny win:

```
(apply str (for [x params] (str "&param=" x)))
```

Then you might prefer `map` over `for` here:

```
(apply str (map #(str "&param=" %) params))
```

`interleave` could work:

```
(apply str (interleave (repeat "&param=") params))
```

You could refactor this to separate the prefix and `interleave` it with the strings:

```
(apply str
       (interleave (repeat \&)
                   (map #(str "param=" %) params)))
```

You might like the look of threading:

```
(->> (map #(str "param=" %) params)
     (interleave (repeat \&))
     (apply str))
```

You could extract a function to do this more generally:

```
(defn prepend-join [separator & cs]
  (apply str (apply interleave (repeat separator) cs)))

(prefix-join \& (map #(str "param=" %) params))
```

Comment: I appreciate the many different options this answer offers, but I do have to say that better than all of them is the original expression in the question.

Comment: I agree that using `str/join` and a `for` loop is the easiest one to read, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

and in addition: 
there is a handy function in clojure's core lib, namely `clojure.pprint/cl-format`

```
user> (clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~{&param=~a~}" [1 2 3 4 5])
;;=> "&param=1&param=2&param=3&param=4&param=5"
```

talking about it's capabilities, it is just the top of the iceberg

Answer (score 2):

Prepending an empty string to `params` looks pretty clean to me:

```
(clojure.string/join "&param=" (cons "" params))
;;=> "&param=1&param=2&param=3&param=4"
```

Comment: I normally like using a sentinal, but this one is a but to tricky for me (i.e. non-obvious to a reader).